# Using global random generator via getStdGen in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've just started learning `Haskell` with the enjoyable reading of "Learn you a Haskell for great Good!" and there is an example in the book which doesn't make sense to me. It says that the following code would output the same random string twice:

```
main = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    putStrLn $ take 20 (randomRs ('a','z') gen)
    gen2 <- getStdGen
    putStrLn $ take 20 (randomRs ('a','z') gen2)
```

On the other hand, if the very same program is called twice it would undoubtedly yield different outputs. Moreover, that doesn't seem consistent if I compare it to the code below which yields different values of `s1` and `s2`:

```
main = do
    s1 <- getLine
    s2 <- getLine
    putStrLn s1
    putStrLn s2
```

I'm wondering how the above two examples are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a specific property of `getStdGen`: unlike `getLine`, it is not an "effectful" IO action, but just accesses the same default random-generator state each time you evaluate it. It is thus almost a pure function, but since it'll be different between different program runs (and indeed within the same run, if you explicitly modify with `setStdGen`), they've nevertheless put it in the `IO` monad.

Perhaps a good analogy is this:

```
main = do
    file <- readFile "/etc/bash.bashrc"  -- or any other persistent system file
    putStrLn $ head (lines file)
    file2 <- readFile "/etc/bash.bashrc"
    putStrLn $ head (lines file2)
```

Comment: Calling `randomRIO` or `randomIO` should also modify it.

Comment: It *is* effectful, and when you put a `setStdGen` in between, it will return a different random generator.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#getStdRandom):

```
-- |Gets the global random number generator.
getStdGen :: IO StdGen
getStdGen  = readIORef theStdGen

theStdGen :: IORef StdGen
theStdGen  = unsafePerformIO $ do
   rng <- mkStdRNG 0
   newIORef rng

mkStdRNG :: Integer -> IO StdGen
mkStdRNG o = do
    ct          <- getCPUTime
    (sec, psec) <- getTime
    return (createStdGen (sec * 12345 + psec + ct + o))
```

So from a practical perspective it's just to do with the implementation of `getStdGen`: it reads a single `IORef` that is initialised once at first use in a given program invocation.